# In SQL, can I find duplicate values in one colum and add their values from another?

Tags: sql

Can I find duplicate values in one column and add their values from another?

For example, I have some member claim information ordered by the date, but they have multiple claims for that same date. Can I add all of the claim totals together and only show the sum of all claims for that specific date?

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSrH1.png)

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: More specifics would be really nice.  The general idea will be to do a SELECT using a GROUP BY, e.g. "SELECT MemberId, Date, SUM(Amount) GROUP BY MemberId, Date".

Comment: I uploaded a picture. I don't know if I can, but the 3 dates that read 2018-2-01 are all for the same person. my question is, is there a way to get the sum of those values and only show the one date?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Rather than post pictures, post the data and your expected result.

```
select sum(capitationamt) as capitationsum, coveragefromdate 
  from datatable
 group by coveragefromdate;
```